Gemfury API started to return "Found more than one package"
I support an application for several languages, and CI artifacts are being pushed to Gemfury. Usually, we push one app version for several languages to the registry. In Gemfury UI, they have always been shown as separate packages. All has been working well for long, long time.

A couple of days back, I started to receive HTTP/1.1 422 Unprocessable Entity response when calling the /versions API:
curl -H "Authorization: ${TOKEN}" -H 'Accept: application/vnd.fury.v1+json' https://api.fury.io/gems/my-test/versions
{"error":{"type":"InputException","message":"Found more than one package"}}%

Has something changed in Gemfury API recently? I tried to find documentation, but does it exist? Is there a way to pull versions for a package plus version request, something like /versions?language=ruby?
